# How can I display country flags using a json script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, html-table

I have a folder of flags (eg):

`gb.png`

`us.png`

And I have a JSON file (countries.json):

```
{
  "GB": "United Kingdom",
  "US": "United States"
}
```

I have a table:

```html
<table>
           <tr>
              <td style="font-family: robotobold; color: white"><b>United Kingdom</b></td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoblack;text-align:right; font-size:10px; color: #aeafaf;">{data1}</td>
              <td  style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #46e08b;"><b>{data2}</b></td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoblack;text-align:right; font-size:10px; color: #aeafaf;">{data3}</td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #F65164"><b>{data4}</b></td>
            </tr>
```

I Would like to add the icon of whatever country is in column 1 before the word.

I have no idea where to start or what to do here - does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I've tried doing this:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var table = document.getElementById("datatable");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j += 4) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("img").src = "us.png"
        }  
    }
}
```

This was an attempt to set all elements to have a US flag.

I also added `<img src="">` on the first `<td>` of each `<tr>`.

However, nothing happens - the us flag does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:
Create an array of the files in the folder that contain the flags but don't include the extension `.png`, for example:

```
var files = ["GB", "US"];
```

Note that they are uppercase, so you should change the names of the files to uppercase.
Then your object:

```
var obj = {
GB: "United Kingdom",
US: "United States"
}
```

With or without quotes it will work the same way.
The best way to loop through Javascript objects is by converting them to arrays first, do this by using:

```
var obj_assoc = Object.entries(obj);
```

This creates an array of arrays with both keys and values of `obj`
You can now create a function to append the data into the table:
This assumes all your files are in uppercase and they have the `.png` extension.
NOTE: I am using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for(const [key, value] of obj_assoc){
$('#mytable tbody').append('<tr><td><img src="path/to/folder/' + key + '.png"/></td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
}
}
```

Comment: It seems you'll just have to spend time and write all of them in an array, since there is no way for Javascript to access the contents in a folder and loop through them. After all, it will all be worthwhile since you will have an array corresponding to the flags in your folder and you can use them however you prefer

Comment: but is there a way for Javascript to get the textcontent of an html element, then match that with something else in a json file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Javascript to get text content of html elements:
for example with jQuery

```
var content = $('.myvalue').text();
```

or if you are using a loop, for multiple values:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < $('.myvalues').length){
    var current_val = $('.myvalues').eq(i);
    //Do something with current_val
    i++;
}
```

Then to compare with the Json file, its better to convert to array again for you to loop easily.
So if you use the same `obj_assoc` as stated in my previous answer, you can compare since it is an array of values

Comment: is `.myvalues` the table name?

Comment: ```.myvalues``` is the class of the ```<td>``` elements that contain your information, for example: ```<td class="myvalues"><b>United Kingdom</b></td>``` just as in your question above, so if you have multiple ```<td>``` elements with that same class, just as in your question where they contain different Nations, you can loop through them and the ```text()``` function will retrieve the text in them ... for example the first ```<td>``` value will return ```United Kingdom```

Comment: ive put this into my html. Where do I go now? Should I add each text item to an Array?

Comment: also, current_val doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the text items right from the while loop, or just compare them with your other external array

```
var i = 0;
while(i < $('.myvalues').length){
    var current_val = $('.myvalues').eq(i).text();
   //Use current_val here
    i++;
}
```

Method 1:

```
var my_array = [];
var i = 0;
while(i < $('.myvalues').length){
    var current_val = $('.myvalues').eq(i).text();
    my_array.push(current_val);
    i++;
}
```

`my_array` will now contain the values from the `<td>` elements

Method 2:

```
var my_other_array = ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5"];
var i = 0;
while(i < $('.myvalues').length){
    var current_val = $('.myvalues').eq(i).text();
    for(var j = 0; j < my_other_array.length; j++){
        if(current_val == my_other_array[j]){
            console.log("Match found");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Match not found");
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Thanks for the correction , this is how it should be:

```
var current_val = $('.myvalues').eq(i).text();
```

I forgot the `text()` function that retrieves the text content

Comment: I need to use Method 1 - however when I console.log(my_array) in console, it is empty

Comment: I've tried the code and it works, try enclosing that whole piece of code in a function e.g: ```function add(){ ... }``` then use ```$(document).ready(function(){ add(); });``` to ensure the content has been loaded before the function is called

Comment: that works, however it also puts every other piece of data into the array - currently I have ['United States','5654','664',1','United Kingdom','7721','853','9','108']

Comment: The only data that will be pushed into the array is the text inside the element that contains the class ```"myvalues"``` for example: ```<td class="myvalues">United Kingdom</td>``` ... you should only enclose the text that you need inside ```"myvalues"``` class, any other content that has been enclosed with that class will also be included in the loop. A sample of the code you're using will work better